# Integrate $\int\frac{x+1}{(x^2-x-5)^3} dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

can you help with this math problem? I dont know how to start? There is any good method? $$\int\frac{x+1}{(x^2-x-5)^3} dx$$

Thank you

Comment: Very similar question ($\int \frac{x+1}{\left(x^2-x+8\right)^3}\, dx$): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1553924/evaluate-int-fracx1x2-x83-dx

Comment: The difference here is that $x^2-x-5$ has real roots, so you can solve it using partial fraction decompositions.

Comment: @user236182: Sorry to ask this here but how one usually finds similar questions or duplicates by searching? How did you do this in case of this question? :)

Comment: @H.R. Well, it's not an exact duplicate, and the question was asked the day before, and I answered it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int \frac{x+1}{\left(x^2-x-5\right)^3}\, dx=\frac{1}{2}\left(\int \frac{d\left(x^2-x-5\right)}{\left(x^2-x-5\right)^3}+\int\frac{3}{\left(x^2-x-5\right)^3}\, dx\right)$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{-2\left(x^2-x-5\right)^2}+96\int \frac{d(2x-1)}{\left((2x-1)^2-21\right)^3}\right)$$

Let $2x-1=u$. We're searching for:

$$\int \frac{1}{(u+\sqrt{21})^3(u-\sqrt{21})^3}\, du$$

Use partial fraction decomposition. After some work you'll find that ([WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=partial+fraction+decomposition+%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%28u%2B%5Csqrt%7B21%7D%29%5E3%28u-%5Csqrt%7B21%7D%29%5E3%7D) gives it):

$$\frac{1}{(u+\sqrt{21})^3(u-\sqrt{21})^3}=\frac{-1}{2352 \sqrt{21} (u+\sqrt{21})}+\frac{-1}{2352 (u+\sqrt{21})^2}$$

$$+\frac{-1}{168 \sqrt{21} (u+\sqrt{21})^3}+\frac{-1}{2352 \sqrt{21} (\sqrt{21}-u)}$$

$$+\frac{-1}{2352 (\sqrt{21}-u)^2}+\frac{-1}{168 \sqrt{21} (\sqrt{21}-u)^3}$$

$$\int \frac{1}{(u+\sqrt{21})^3(u-\sqrt{21})^3}\, du=\frac{-1}{2352\sqrt{21}}\int \frac{d(u+\sqrt{21})}{u+\sqrt{21}}$$

$$+\frac{-1}{2352}\int \frac{d(u+\sqrt{21})}{(u+\sqrt{21})^2}+\frac{-1}{168 \sqrt{21}}\int\frac{d(u+\sqrt{21})}{(u+\sqrt{21})^3}$$

$$+\frac{1}{2352 \sqrt{21}} \int\frac{d(\sqrt{21}-u)}{\sqrt{21}-u}+$$

$$+\frac{1}{2352}\int\frac{d(\sqrt{21}-u)}{(\sqrt{21}-u)^2}+\frac{1}{168 \sqrt{21}}\int\frac{d(\sqrt{21}-u)}{(\sqrt{21}-u)^3},$$

which is equal to:

$$\frac{-1}{2352\sqrt{21}}\ln|u+\sqrt{21}|+\frac{1}{2352(u+\sqrt{21})}+\frac{1}{336 \sqrt{21}(u+\sqrt{21})^2}$$

$$+\frac{1}{2352 \sqrt{21}}\ln|\sqrt{21}-u|+\frac{-1}{2352(\sqrt{21}-u)}+\frac{-1}{336 \sqrt{21}(\sqrt{21}-u)^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

1) Use **partial fraction** to decompose the integrand

$\eqalign{
  & f = {{x + 1} \over {{{\left( {{x^2} - x - 5} \right)}^3}}}  \cr 
  & \,\,\,\, = \mathop \sum \limits_{r = RootOf\left( {{x^2} - x - 5} \right)} {{{r \over {147}} + {1 \over {49}}} \over {{{\left( {x - r} \right)}^3}}} + \mathop \sum \limits_{r = RootOf\left( {{x^2} - x - 5} \right)} {{ - {r \over {441}} - {4 \over {441}}} \over {{{\left( {x - r} \right)}^2}}} + \mathop \sum \limits_{r = RootOf\left( {{x^2} - x - 5} \right)} {{ - {1 \over {1029}} + {{2r} \over {1029}}} \over {x - r}} \cr} $

2) Integrate the decomposed integrand

Comment: i think it is not so simple, the printing of the solution of your CAS proves this

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: Yes, you are right! :) Doing the computation by hand is frustrating in this case! Do we have to the computation by hand? :) Just wanted to give the hint! :)

Comment: @PatrikD: There seem to be no easy way for computing this. The normal procedure is explained in the above answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

As in my other answer,

$$\int \frac{x+1}{\left(x^2-x-5\right)^3}\, dx=\frac{1}{2}\left(\int \frac{d\left(x^2-x-5\right)}{\left(x^2-x-5\right)^3}+\int\frac{3}{\left(x^2-x-5\right)^3}\, dx\right)$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{-2\left(x^2-x-5\right)^2}+3\cdot 2^5\int \frac{d(2x-1)}{\left((2x-1)^2-21\right)^3}\right)$$

Let $2x-1=\sqrt{21}\sin u$. Then $d(2x-1)=\sqrt{21}\cos u\, du$.

$$\int \frac{d(2x-1)}{\left((2x-1)^2-21\right)^3}=\frac{1}{21^2\sqrt{21}}\int \frac{1}{-\cos^5 u}\, du$$

Now integrate by parts. Here are some hints:

$$\int \sec^5 u\, du=\int \sec^3 u\, d\left(\tan u\right)=\sec^3 u\tan u-\int \left(3\sec^2 u\cdot \sec u\tan u\right)\tan u\, du$$

$$\int \sec^3 u\tan^2 u\, du=\int \sec^3 u\left(\sec^2 u-1\right)\, du=\int \sec^5 u\, du-\int \sec^3 u\, du$$

$$\int \sec^3 u\, du=\int \sec u\, d(\tan u)=\sec u\tan u-\int (\sec u\tan u)(\tan u)\, du$$

$$\int \sec u\tan^2 u\, du=\int \sec\left(\sec^2 u-1\right)\, du=\int \sec^3 u\, du-\int \sec u\, du$$

Now, there are many ways to solve $\int \sec u\, du$. See [Ways to evaluate $\int \sec \theta \, \mathrm d \theta$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6695/ways-to-evaluate-int-sec-theta-mathrm-d-theta) (including the question body). You can always use the [Tangent Half-Angle substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) on rational $\sin x,\cos x$ integrals, including $\int \sec u\, du$.